# Como fazer uma lista de contatos no Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Estou criando no delphi uma lista de contatos, igual de telefone, mas precisava fazer aquela barra lateral com as letras de A - Z e quando ele clicar em alguma letra o vscrool iria para os contados da letra selecionada.
Os contato eu vou utilizar a list view, mas as letras eu não sei se seria viável fazer com Trectangle.
Sabem se existe algo assim nativo ou uma forma de criar isso?

[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Comment: Isso no APP para celular, não no Desktop, certo?